# Read 3DSOLID properties from c#

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, dxf, dwg

I have both a .dwg and a .dxf file from which i have to extraxt some entities. I can extract all kind of  entities but 3DSOLId. Is there a programmaticaly(c#) way to extract those entities and read their properties?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide what you have tried so far in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In old versions of DXF (before AutoCAD 2013/AC1027), geometry data for 3DSOLID was written as SAT data (some documentation of this format can be found here: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/sat/sat.pdf) in a DXF code 1. The data was encrypted with an XOR 95.

Since Autodesk has replaced ACIS with Autodesk Shape Manager (ASM), the data is encoded in another form, not documented.